# Stuck in Smart Contract

Tags: wallets, etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp, blocks

I paid the fees on ethereum for item but received nothing what can I do for this? I think there is an error in smart contract please check for me my address is 0x4F3Eddd049E828C0A0714D8E3E8B2B2bA23A82DB and the trans id is 0x0f2d4517451c5cf6c3e55c51543bbfb79e273057a3de9150408cd234f00904db
I paid fees for mined ETH collection but received nothing any solution for this please help me I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

The [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0f2d4517451c5cf6c3e55c51543bbfb79e273057a3de9150408cd234f00904db) is calling the method **payForItem()** of the contract [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x17e7d164f48f9e52ae9312288496a7e181263606#code). And the method is actually doing nothing:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.26;

contract MyShopNew {

  address private  owner;

  constructor() public{   
    owner=0xe067E6687fCd0fB8C3Ed1808311966605B62f30c;
  }

  function getOwner(
  ) public view returns (address) {    
    return owner;
  }

  function withdraw() public {
    require(owner == msg.sender);
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

  function payForItem() public payable {
  }

  function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return address(this).balance;
  }
}
```